# Display many rows instead of 1

Tags: php

Im displaying tables of my records from my database, but when it shows the record, it displays many of it, i dont know why, but i only need 1 row of it yet it displays maybe thousands of it. seems like there was a problem dispalying rows and i need help on that. Thank you very much ............................................................

```
<?php
include("auth_admin.php");


if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
// search in all table columns
// using concat mysql function
$query = "SELECT * FROM `lcho_dengue_activities` where `month`= '".$valueToSearch."' ";
$search_result = filterTable($query);


 }
  else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM `lcho_dengue_activities`";
$search_result = filterTable($query);

 }

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "lcho_login");
$filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if (!$filter_Result) {
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connect));
   exit();
 }
     return $filter_Result;
 }


 ?>

<form action="filterdata.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Vaccine</th>
                <th>San Francisco</th>
                <th>San Celestino</th>
                <th>Malitlit</th>
                <th>Sto. Toribio</th>
                <th>San Benito</th>
                <th>Sto. Nino</th>
                <th>San Isidro</th>
                <th>Munting Pulo</th>
                <th>Latag</th>
                <th>Sabang</th>
                <th>Tipacan</th>
                <th>San Jose</th>
                <th>Tangob</th>
                <th>Antipolo del Norte</th>
                <th>Antipolo del Sur</th>
                <th>Pinagkawitan</th>
            </tr>

  <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php 
              echo "boom";

            ?></td>
                <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE barangay_id= '1'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>

            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num1 FROM lcho_childcare WHERE barangay_id= '2'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num1'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num1'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '3'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '4'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '5'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '6'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '7'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '8'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '9'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '10'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '11'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '12'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '13'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '14'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '15'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            <td><?php mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
            mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(`ccare_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_childcare WHERE  barangay_id= '16'  ");

            $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

              echo $row['ind_num'];

            };?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php endwhile;?>
        </table>
    </form>
```

[image: Hope this picture helps you understand]

Comment: 1st: connect only _once_ to your database

Comment: 2nd: why don't you do _one_ query (like `WHERE barangay_id IN (1,2,3,4..16)`)

Comment: 3rd: you'd need to `GROUP BY barangay_id` to get only one row back for SUM

Comment: can you give me an example query sir? thanks ♥

Comment: @CarloBarrogo can you add your database tables and structure in the question?

Comment: 4th: you don't use/display any results from your first (search-) query, though loopinig through all the rows. To me it's not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: @IftieaqMurshed 
i have 
(id, district_id, barangay_id,month,year,gender, ccare_ind1....ccare_ind35 , date
im displaying column as rows

Comment: @jeff that was for filtering data and i want to discover first this problem then ill jump to that filter

Comment: Take a picture of your "lcho_dengue_activities" and "lcho_childcare" table  structure and add it to the question. Your code is not clear. I can't suggest anything without knowing your exact entity–relationship model.

Comment: You've vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks with that code, you should use prepared statements. Also you've got a mix of functions from the mysql_ extension and the mysqli_ extension. You shouldn't now be using the mysql_ extension as it was ***REMOVED*** from PHP as of version 7.0 of PHP

Comment: @IftieaqMurshed already change it from "lcho_dengue_activities" to "lcho_childcare"
here is my "lcho_childcare" 
https://imgur.com/a/oIqAK17

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Thank you for that comment ill adjust it

Comment: Please read how to create an [mcve] - focus on _minimal_.  Additionally, for questions like this, please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/870729